# Extract text within a div tag that has no class or id

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request, python-re

I want to extract the text from div but it has no class or ID to sort by, I just want the text in between. I put [39] because that's the 39th div tag on the webpage.  Thanks !

```
import bs4 
from urllib.request import urlopen 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import lxml

result = requests.get("https://naruto-arena.net/char/Uzumaki-Naruto")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')


div = soup.find_all('div')[39]
print(div)
```

Result:

```
<div style="min-height: 80px;padding: 3px;background-color: #FAFAFA;">
<img align="left" class="border" src="https://naruto-arena.net/uploads/skills/1/large.jpg" 
style="margin: 2px 5px 2px 0px;"/>Naruto's version of the Lion Combo. This skill deals 20 damage to 
one enemy. During 'Shadow Clones' 
this skill will deal 10 additional damage.
                    </div>
```

Desired:

Naruto's version of the Lion Combo. This skill deals 20 damage to one enemy. During 'Shadow Clones' 
this skill will deal 10 additional damage.

Comment: Try `print(div.text)` instead of `print(div)`.

Comment: It worked thanks !